# Query that filters with two string in two diferent columns or in the same column

Tags: sql

I have a filter that uses surnames to find people. I have one textbox with the name, and another one with the surname. The problem is that when the person have two surnames, and one of them is made with two words, it doesn't found anything.

For example:
Kevin "Gonzalez" Fernandez -> found it correctly
Kevin "De la Fuente" Fernandez -> don't found anything

I put on the example to clarify that both are the first surname, one with one word, the other one with 3 words.

In my BBDD I have two columns, each for a surname (surname1 and surname2, for example). And I don't know when is surname1 or surname2 the surname that have more than one word, I mean, in the first example "Gonzalez" is surname1 and "Fernandez" is surname2, but with De la Fuente, I don't know if "De" is surname1 or it is "De la" or it is "De la fuente"...

So, I think I have to do a select that combine both columns and then checks if this is the same as the Surname input. I do that using an example I see here:

```
SELECT *
FROM GPCP_INTERESADO A
WHERE REPLACE(A.CD_APELL1 || a.cd_apell2,' ','') like (REPLACE('garcia',' ',''))
```

But it doesn't works, it doesn't give me any result.

Can anyone helps me? Thanks a lot!

Comment: what about `WHERE A.CD_APELL1 || a.cd_apell2 LIKE '%Garcia%'`

Comment: do you mean this? SELECT * FROM GPCP_INTERESADO A WHERE REPLACE(A.CD_APELL1 || a.cd_apell2,'%Garcia%','') like (REPLACE('%Garcia%',' ',''))

Comment: same result, it gives me anything

Comment: If you can find a library based on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance It may provide help.